# React Native onPress Function

Tags: react-native

can somebody give me a detailed overview on how to run a component in a different .js file on a click on touchable opacity using hooks, step-by-step process, I have tried to run using functional components but just couldn't figure, both ways are highly accepted

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Just wanna go from 1 functional component to another on press of a button, like changing screens on pressing of a button